# How to multiply two sequences in C# using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

How to multiply two sequences in C# using lambda expressions? For example, if I have `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`, I want the result to be `{3,4,6,8}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lambda expressions:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2 };
int[] b = new int[] { 3, 4 };
var c = a.SelectMany(i => b.Select(j => i * j));
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `SelectMany` to both generate the Cartesian Product and multiply the two values together.

```
var query = from x in first
            from y in second
            select x * y;
```

Comment: I don't think I'd consider query syntax as using lambda expressions.

Comment: @GWB But they *are* using lambda expressions.  You're just not writing them out explicitly.  The code is literally exactly equivalent to having written it out in method syntax; it's merely a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your first array called first and a second one called second, you can do this.

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
first.ToList().ForEach(x => second.ToList().ForEach(y => result .Add(x * y)));
```